# Facebook social app in C#/ ASP.NET- 'Could not find schema...' for facebookSettings et al

Tags: asp.net, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-social-plugins

I have been editing the basic example code for the Social app for Facebook- which work fine, 
(CSASPNETFacebookApp) but if I change very much within the Default.aspx, I crash out with 
'Could not find schema information for the element ..."
facebookSettings
appId
appSecret
canvasPage

I have trawled various sites, and seen a problem close to this - and tried doing an XML / Create schema, which gives a Web.xsd file- but stil the same problem.

Has anyone seen anything like this before- I get the same on 2 computers.

In comparing back to the original Default file, if I ensure that it is line perfect within the editor (new version with a backup verion of the original download), I still get the schema error.

Sorry if this sounds vague- but I must be missing something fundamental here!

Kindest, jonathan.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is a problem with your web.config.

You should have this in there in the configuration section:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="facebookSettings" 
     type="Facebook.FacebookConfigurationSection"/>
</configSections>

<facebookSettings
  appSecret="app secret"
  appId="app id"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like:-

```
<facebookSettings
  appId = "cut out"
  appSecret = "cut out"
  canvasPage = "cut out"
  canvasUrl ="cut out"
  cancelUrlPath = "" />
```

....! All this works perfectly, but, for example, if I cut & paste in some DB schema info- such as

```
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
    <add name="LocalSqlServer"
        connectionString= "Data Source=DF-Workstation;Initial Catalog= (deleted log in stuff)
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

...then all the Facebook stuff 'disappears' (Message    2   Could not find schema information for the element 'facebookSettings'.   C:\Devs\FacebookSDK\Samples\CSASPNETFacebookApp\Web.config  11  6   C:...\CSASPNETFacebookApp)

If I now delete all the

Anyone any other ideas?